# undefined: x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey when calling on *rsa.PublicKey

Tags: go

I'm having trouble accessing the `PublicKey` field of `*rsa.PrivateKey`

Whenever I call `x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey(keyBytes.PublicKey)` in the code below, I get:

```
[tony@localhost app]$ go run gencsr.go
# command-line-arguments
./gencsr.go:37:90: undefined: x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey
```

As you can see, I've included the `x509` package and I'm able to access `keyBytes.PublicKey` and see that it's of type `PublicKey`.

Sources:
[crypto/x509](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#MarshalPKCS1PublicKey)
[crypto/rsa](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#PrivateKey)

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "crypto/x509/pkix"
    "encoding/asn1"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
)

var oidEmailAddress = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 2, 840, 113549, 1, 9, 1}

func main() {

    email := ""
    subj := pkix.Name{
        CommonName:         "example.com",
        Country:            []string{"US"},
        Province:           []string{"New York"},
        Locality:           []string{"Albany"},
        Organization:       []string{"My Company Ltd"},
        OrganizationalUnit: []string{"IT"},
    }
    bits := 4096

    key, csr := genCSR(subj, email, bits)
    fmt.Printf(key)
    fmt.Printf(csr)

}

func genCSR(subj pkix.Name, email string, bits int) (pemKey, csr string) {

    keyBytes, _ := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, bits)
    pemPubKey := string(pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "RSA PUBLIC KEY", Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey(keyBytes.PublicKey)}))
    pemKey = string(pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "RSA PRIVATE KEY", Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(keyBytes)}))
    fmt.Printf(pemPubKey)

    rawSubj := subj.ToRDNSequence()
    if len(email) > 0 {
        rawSubj = append(rawSubj, []pkix.AttributeTypeAndValue{
            {Type: oidEmailAddress, Value: email},
        })
    }

    asn1Subj, _ := asn1.Marshal(rawSubj)
    template := x509.CertificateRequest{
        RawSubject:         asn1Subj,
        SignatureAlgorithm: x509.SHA256WithRSA,
    }

    csrBytes, _ := x509.CreateCertificateRequest(rand.Reader, &template, keyBytes)
    csr = string(pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "CERTIFICATE REQUEST", Bytes: csrBytes}))

    return pemKey, csr
}
```

Answer (score 2):

x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey is [new in Go 1.10](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#crypto/x509). You are probably running an older version.

If you can't upgrade: [the function is very simple](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/9dbeb92711b86ed4f0a37ad6ce465fb2d9053f2f) and you can just copy it into your own package:

```
// pkcs1PublicKey reflects the ASN.1 structure of a PKCS#1 public key.
type pkcs1PublicKey struct {
    N *big.Int
    E int
}

// MarshalPKCS1PublicKey converts an RSA public key to PKCS#1, ASN.1 DER form.
func MarshalPKCS1PublicKey(key *rsa.PublicKey) []byte {
    derBytes, _ := asn1.Marshal(pkcs1PublicKey{
            N: key.N,
            E: key.E,
    })
    return derBytes
}
```

Comment: `go version`'s output is something like 1.9.4 -- Not booted into Linux so I can't say with certainty. So thank you.

Comment: Btw, Peter's answer should be voted best if anyone has the rep to do it. Upgrading to 1.10 solved my issues. I did have to change `keyBytes.PublicKey` to `&keyBytes.PublicKey` since the function requires type `*rsa.PublicKey`. Thanks Peter!

Answer (score 0):

RSA public key can be generated this way:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"

    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main(){
    key, b, err := generatePrivateKey()
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(b))

    public2, err := generateSSHPublicKey(key)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(public2))
}

func generatePrivateKey() (*rsa.PrivateKey, []byte, error) {
    // keyBytes, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    keyBytes, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 4096)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    certBytes := new(bytes.Buffer)

    err = pem.Encode(certBytes, &pem.Block{Type: "RSA PRIVATE KEY", Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(keyBytes)})
    if err != nil{
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    return keyBytes, certBytes.Bytes(), nil
}

func generateSSHPublicKey(key *rsa.PrivateKey) ([]byte, error){

    public, err := ssh.NewPublicKey(&key.PublicKey) // *rsaPublicKey
    if err != nil{
        return nil, err
    }

    certBytes := new(bytes.Buffer)

    err = pem.Encode(certBytes, &pem.Block{Type: "PUBLIC KEY", Bytes: public.Marshal()})
    if err != nil{
        return nil, err
    }

    return certBytes.Bytes(), nil
}
```